# How to block second (or later) HTTP request until the first request process is done. [Node.JS / Firebase cloud function]

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

Let's say Server(Node JS) process time for HTTP request is 10 sec when I click submit button. and then I double click this button at the same time. Process time of this situation about 10 sec. (Like a parallel processing)

I don't want this. And I want to server block second request until first process finish. So my requirement is spending time about 20+ sec.

Please help me find out the solution or suggest some node js library.

Comment: Track request somehow (i.e. cookie) and at server side update the list of under processing requests (like some promises in array) then every time a new request comes, check if there is a other one is under process or not.

Comment: One possible idea (and I have NOT thought it all through) is to leverage Cloud Tasks (https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/).  Using this you could pipeline your work.  Cloud Tasks has a concept of max concurrent dispatches.  If set to 1, then you should only ever have one task running at a time (serialization).

Answer (score 0):

Add the requests into a queue. and then process the queue one after the other.

i Could find a npm package - I haven't used it.

[node-request-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-request-queue)

Edit: This is purely nodejs perspective. if you take into account cloud functions or Lambda, this might not work

Comment: Sadly, I don't think this will work (I would be delighted to be wrong).  I think this technology is for serializing work within a single Node.js runtime instance as opposed to across multiple Node.js instances.  If I read the OP correctly, this is a Cloud Function story and one must assume that each function could just as easily run on its own Node.js runtime (likely on physically distinct underlying hardware platforms).

Comment: @Kolban You are right. My brain ignored the cloud function part,